# Java 8 - get a Map of parent directory and list of subdirectories

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a folder structure like this:

```
/home/user/root/
                dir1/
                     subDir1/
                             pdf1.pdf
                             log1.log
                     subDir2/
                             somefile.txt
                     subDir3
                dir2/
                     subDir1
                     subDir4
                     subDir5
                abc.txt
                def.pdf
                xyz.log
```

and so on

I have the requirement that given the input path "/home/user/root/", get a `Map<String, List<String>>` as below:

```
key: dir1, value: [subDir1, subDir2, subDir3]
key: dir2, value: [subDir1, subDir4, subDir5]
...
...
```

That is, the keys of the map are the directories first level under the given input and then each key has a value that is list of subdirectories under it at first level.

I am able to get a list of first level directories:

```
private Set<String> listFilesUsingFileWalk(String rootDir, int depth) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(rootDir);
        try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(path, depth)) {
            return stream
                    .filter(file -> Files.isDirectory(file) && !file.equals(path))
                    .map(Path::getFileName)
                    //.forEach(d -> System.out.println(d.getFileName()));
                    .map(Path::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        }
    }
```

But not able to get the required output. I am thinking that may be recursion can be a solution but can't think of it in terms of Java 8 streams.

Please can this be advised?

Comment: What would depth mean? In your requirements you only state first level as key and second level as value. So, is it always that depth?

Comment: ```depth``` would be 1 for dir1, dir2, etc. and 2 (from root) for subDir1, subDir2, etc.

Comment: Is there no chance that subdirectory name is to parent directory?

Comment: No. ```root```, ```parentDir``` under root and ```subDirs``` under parentDir will always have a different name

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure about the purpose of your depth parameter. But it looks like you are looking for something like this:

```java
private Map<String,List<String>> listFilesUsingFileWalk(String rootDir, int depth) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(rootDir);
        try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(path, depth)) {
            return stream
                    .filter(file -> Files.isDirectory(file) && !file.equals(path))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            (p) -> p.getFileName().toString(),
                            (p) -> Arrays.stream(p.toFile().listFiles()).filter(File::isDirectory).map(File::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())
                    ));
        }
}
```

or (without using the File class)

```java
private Map<String,List<String>> listFilesUsingFileWalk(String rootDir, int depth) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(rootDir);
        try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(path, depth)) {
            return stream
                    .filter(file -> Files.isDirectory(file) && !file.equals(path))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            (p) -> p.getFileName().toString(),
                            (p) -> {
                                try {
                                    return Files.list(p).filter(Files::isDirectory).map(Path::getFileName).map(Path::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    return Collections.emptyList();
                                }
                            }
                    ));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your names of the directories are unique, you can follow this approach. **Also you don't need recursion**.

```
Map<String, List<String>> collect = stream
                .filter(file -> Files.isDirectory(file) && !file.equals(path))
                .filter(file -> !file.getParent().equals(path))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getParent().getFileName().toString(), Collectors.mapping(p -> p.getFileName().toString(), Collectors.toList())));
```

*Note: This will give you all the parent child directories.*

```
private Map<String, List<String>> listFilesUsingFileWalk(String rootDir, int depth) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(rootDir);
    Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(path, depth);
    return stream
                .filter(file -> Files.isDirectory(file) && !file.equals(path))
                .filter(file -> !file.getParent().equals(path))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getParent().getFileName().toString(), Collectors.mapping(p -> p.getFileName().toString(), Collectors.toList())));
}
```

Comment: Hi Ray, this solution gives me the output similiar to what my code had produced:
{rootDir=[dir1, dir2]}. However, code from dajavx gave the required output. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @curious_brain I have updated my answers to meet your requirement